# Approximate selection between decimal values in perl-DBI

Tags: mysql

I was developed database table by using this query

```
create table test(
  id varchar(10),
  alpha varchar(1000),
  marks decimal(10,4)
);
```

In the `marks` should use decimal datatypes.

```
marks column
1100.2523
1100.2722
733.8375
1192.257
587.6248
392.0859
```

I should use to select query

```
select * from test where marks="1100.2625";
```

and

```
select * from test where marks="392.0252";
```

The output is `Empty set (0.00 sec)`

Expected Output is

```
1100.2523 1100.2722 and 392.0859 this rows.
```

If possible to select between decimal range.?

Comment: The last select `select * from test where marks="392.0252";` does not look like approximate even by doing rounding to first decimal point. You have to decide some benchmark for the approximation else just by using comparison its not possible to get what you are looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually not possible using the query and for that you need to define a benchmark for the approximation.

Now if you have a bench mark set for the approximation and lets say its something as

1. If the marks and compared value is same rounding to first decimal point then its a match.
2. If the after rounding to first decimal point both marks and input and taking the difference the value is `1` or `-1` then its a match.

Using the above benchmark it could done.

Consider the following table

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+------+-------+-----------+
| id   | alpha | marks     |
+------+-------+-----------+
| 1    | aa    | 1100.2523 |
| 2    | bb    | 1100.2722 |
| 3    | cc    |  392.0859 |
+------+-------+-----------+


mysql> select * from test where round(marks,1) = round(1100.2625,1);
+------+-------+-----------+
| id   | alpha | marks     |
+------+-------+-----------+
| 1    | aa    | 1100.2523 |
| 2    | bb    | 1100.2722 |
+------+-------+-----------+


mysql> select * from test 
where round(marks,1) = round(392.0252,1) 
or round(marks,1) - round(392.0252,1) = 0.1 
or round(marks,1) - round(392.0252,1) = -0.1; 
+------+-------+----------+
| id   | alpha | marks    |
+------+-------+----------+
| 3    | cc    | 392.0859 |
+------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty,i have to select 1010.6367 and 1201.4474 by using this query ` select * from test where round(marks,1) = round(1100.2625,1);` . its possible.?? I want to select before 200 and after 200 of given input.. Please help me.

Comment: Yes so as I said the benchmark needs to be predefined, so check my 2nd example which you can use for `-ve` and `+ve` difference.

Comment: Yes, Thank you , But before decimal, how shall i fix the benchmark.? after decimal i understood. Before it seems.? Round off in the sense after decimal its right..

Comment: Thats correct, but once you take the difference after rounds of it will get the difference of full data. so `1010.6367 and 1201.4474` if you compare with `1100.2625` and if the benchmark is `+ -` 200 then  need  just `round(marks)-round(input) <= 200 and round(marks)-round(input) >=-200` will get the job done

Comment: oh Nice @Abhik Chakraborty.. Thank you so much

Comment: The above is well working in Mysql.. But this same query i will try to use in Perl-CGI program. Its not working..  Anybody give me a suggestion please..

Comment: I think you need to add a separate questions with the query and the perl code tagged with `perl` `mysql` so that someone with perl knowledge may find the issue.